# How to filter ComboBox itemssource based on other ComboBox selected item in WPF-C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a *list of Clients* and two `ComboBox` that named **cmbList1**, **cmbList2**.

Based on MVVM Model i create `ObservableCollection` for first list :

```
private ObservableCollection<Client> MyFirstList = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
public ObservableCollection<Client> myfirlist
{
    get { return myfirlist; }
    set
    {
        this.myfirlist=value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("myfirstlist");
    }
}
```

and there is my second list i create for adding filtered first list.

```
private ObservableCollection<Client> myseclist = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
```

now how can i show this filtered in XAML and also how to filtered in code behind?

Comment: Do you really need to use Linq? For this kind of behavior, I would better use `ICollectionView`, so only one `ObservableCollection` will be used for both ComboList. This is if you use binding?

Comment: I am confused you want to achieve it with Link as the question states or with binding? can you clarify more if you are flexible on not using Link then please edit the question

Comment: Please use Linq instead of Link. @Cfun, also i am not using MVVM and binding. if binding is use full i use binding instead of Linq

Comment: How to acheive it by using binding? @Siegfried.V

Comment: @NEBEZ just answered. In fact I think for that, using binding and `ICollectionView` is the best way for you, if you are already familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your ViewModel, you create an ObservableCollection :

```
private ObservableCollection<Client> MyFirstList = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
public ObservableCollection<Client> myFirstList
{
    get { return myFirstList; }
    set
    {
        this.myFirstList=value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyFirstList");
    }
}
```

Then you create an `ICollectionView` :

```
public ICollectionView MySecondListView { get; set; }
```

When you call your ViewModel, you need to "link" the view to the first list :

```
MySecondListView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyFirstList);
```

So `MySecondListView` will just be a "copy" of your First list.

STEP 2 : Filter

You need to bind selected element from the 1st ComboBox, and everytime its value changed, apply a filter to your ICollectionView :

```
private Client selectedClient = null;
public Client SelectedClient
{
    get { return selectedClient; }
    set
    {
        this.selectedClient = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedClient");
        MySecondListView.Filter=new Predicate<object>(GetFilteredView);
    }
}
private bool getFilteredView(object obj)
{
    Client client = (Client)obj;
    if(this.SelectedClient!=null && client==this.SelectedClient) return false;
    return true;
}
```

On that way, the second list will return the same as the 1st one, without selected item.

Then finally XAML :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="FirstComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyFirstList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedClient, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ComboBox x:Name="SecondComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MySecondListView}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
```

**EDIT : Without MVVM :**

In that case you can use `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` or `ComboBox.SelectedItem` and do something like that :

- In your XAML use the event "SelectionChanged"

then you can make a function like that :

```
private void MyFirstComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MySecondList.Clear();
    for(int i=0;i<MyFirstList.Count();i++)
    {
        if(i!=MyComboBox.SelectedIndex) MySecondList.Add(MyFirstList[i];
        //if(MyFirstList[i]!=MyComboBox.SelectedItem) MySecondList.Add(MyFirstList[i];
    }
}
```

But then you need to define 2 separated ObservableCollection.

Comment: I just want to know. Does using `CollectionViewSource` consumes like the same memory of  the original `ObservableCollection`, so it is double?

Comment: Is a solution based on a converter will consume less memory?

Comment: @Cfun sincerely I don't know about memory. The main advantage I noticed using `ICollectionView` is that on the end you need to manage only one `ObservableCollection`, so for coding it is much easier on the end, on a big project it is of a great help.

Comment: @Siegfried.V your answer is great, but problem is that i do not use MVVM for my project, it must be resolve on code behind.

Comment: @NEBEZ just edited answer, without MVVM you may do 2 separate ObservableCollection

Comment: Great answer thanks. @Siegfried.V